# Laravel 5 Model mocking

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5, mockery

I have seen a few posts in various places about this and they all seem to have a similar answer. However for the life of me I cannot get the Mockery object working properly.

The Attribute model looks like this

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model {

    public function test()
    {
        return (new \App\Models\Value())->hello();
    }
}
```

The Value model like this

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Value extends Model
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'goodbye';
    }
}
```

The PHPUnit test looks like this

```
use App\Models\Attribute;

class AttributeModelTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testThing()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock('\App\Models\Value');

        $mock->shouldReceive('hello')
           ->once()
           ->andReturn('hello');

        $this->app->instance('\App\Models\Value', $mock);

       $a = new \App\Models\Attribute();
       $return = $a->test();
       var_dump($return);
    }
}
```

PHPUnit outputs 'goodbye', where I though that I am telling it to return 'hello' in the mock and it doesn't. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change *$a = new \App\Models\Attribute();* with *$a = App::make('App\Models\Value');* ?

Comment: If I do that it will basically be the same as calling `$mock->hello()`. Not sure if it's clear but I'm trying to mock the response that is used by `Attribute`. if I call $mock->hello() it returns the expected value of 'hello'

Comment: You are right, I got confused between both classes, I think it should work if you change *return (new \App\Models\Value())->hello();* with *return (App::make('App\Models\Value'))->hello();* and in the test: *$a = new \App\Models\Attribute();* with *$a = App::make('App\Models\Attribute');* so Laravel will resolve the dependencies through the container.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I thought this was the path you might be suggesting and started to follow it through but hit a bit of a wall. Your prompt made me dig a bit deeper and try something which works, I'll answer my own question unless you want to. Within the Model it's important to do `\App::make('Blah')` otherwise namespacing kills it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments:

Change `return (new \App\Models\Value())->hello();` with `return (\App::make('App\Models\Value'))->hello();`

And in the test: `$a = new \App\Models\Attribute();` with `$a = App::make('App\Models\Attribute');` so Laravel will resolve the dependencies through the container